# Invalid datetime error

Tags: python, python-datetime, try-except

I am using datefinder module to find date references in the text. However, the generator returned by the function call might return invalid dates. How to tackle this using a try-except block?

```
import datefinder
file = open('abc.txt', 'r')    
for text in file:
     dates = datefinder.find_dates(text)

     for one_date in dates:        #Getting an error at this point if date is not in the range
         if valid_date(one_date):
             #some code here
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What happens when an invalid date is returned?

Comment: Valueerror is obtained. The parser might return invalid dates say for example >2000 as a year

Answer (score 0):

```
import datefinder
file = open('abc.txt', 'r')    
for text in file:
       dates = datefinder.find_dates(text)
       while True:
                    try:
                        one, flag = self.valid_date((str1.__iter__()).next())
                        if flag:
                            *some code here*
                    except ValueError:
                        continue
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
```